# What is the best way for unmanaged code to view data stored in a Windows Azure blob as a file?

Tags: c#, azure

I have a Windows Azure service, and want to use an unmanaged library to process a file. The API currently requires an input file name and output file name, but I have some control over this library. Is there an easy way to do this for files currently being stored in a blob? I've read that mounting a blob as a drive requires a bit of extra effort and possibly external software, which I'd like to avoid. I could copy the files to azure drive storage, but that method seems sub-optimal. My original thought was to read the data from the blob into memory in my manager worker, and pass an unmanaged pointer to the data to the library, which would then pass my a pointer to memory representing the output of the library; would this be the most efficient solution in an azure environment?

Some clarification on the flow of events:

1. Document is created by webrole1 in memory
2. Document is uploaded to blob storage
3. worker1 realizes there is a document
4. worker1 needs to utilize functionality in a c++ library, NativeCode.dll. NativeCode.dll exports a single function, `ProcessFile(const char * input, const char * output)`.
5. worker1 [*does something*], and calls `ProcessFile(*some file path*, *another file path*)`, thereby not unnecessarily copying the original file.

It's #5 that I don't know how to do; I need functionality similar to:

```
string path = myBlob.GetPathToBlob();
var handle = File.Open(path);
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by `use an unmanaged library to process a file`? What kind of processing are you doing?

Comment: The specific type of processing isn't overly important, except to say that it has to be in the library mentioned. Currently, it takes a file in and spits a file out, but can likely be modified to take a buffer in and give a pointer to a buffer out.

Comment: Well, the question actually arose because I don't see why you can't take the most obvious approach, doing the processing before saving the blob to the storage account. If performance is not an issue using a different back-end store then it shouldn't be an issue using azure storage. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see! In this case, the document is received via a web role, and processed by a worker role - it's never actually written to disk (besides the blob)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to have the worker (where I presume the unmanaged code is at), lease the blob in question, download it to the localstorage location, let the c++ code operate on it (since at this points its just a file on local disk), then upload the altered file back into blob storage and release the lease.

Just make sure the wrap the heck out of all this to ensure proper cleanup of the file and the blob lease.